# Calling NSBeep in NSNumberFormatter subclass

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsnumberformatter

I have subclassed `NSNumberFormatter` so I may control what a user is allowed to type into a `NSTextField`, and when they hit an invalid key I need to play the beep sound via `NSBeep();`. While this does work - the beep is played, Xcode shows a warning on that line: `Implicit declaration of function 'NSBeep' is invalid in C99`. How can that be resolved? This call resides in `isPartialStringValid:newEditingString:errorDescription:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the `AppKit Framework`.

**Objective-C**

```
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>  // oldschool
@import AppKit;  // neueschool
```

**Swift**

```
import AppKit
```

[*AppKit Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Miscellaneous/AppKit_Functions/)